# How to make an ant design custom them with sass?

Tags: css, sass

I Want to change the border color of the input fields in ant design library when the user hovers over them.
I changed the borders when the user focuses on them by:

```
.ant-input:focus {
  border-color: #7363dc;
  outline: 0;
}
```

but could not do the same for hover

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover)

> The :hover CSS pseudo-class matches when the user interacts with an element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it. It is generally triggered when the user hovers over an element with the cursor (mouse pointer).

```
.ant-input:hover {
    border-color: #7363dc;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```css
input {
  max-width: 400px;
}
.ant-input:focus {
  border-color: red !important;
  outline: 0;
}

.ant-input:hover {
  border-color: green !important;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.4.1/antd.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input class="ant-input" placeholder="Input field">
```

As an alternative (probably cleaner) solution, it looks like Ant Design UI allows you to customize your theme through defined variables. See:

https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Comment: @ayakhaled since you're overwriting a property in a vendor CSS you could explore the original CSS file to check `.ant-input:hover` for specificity or just use `!important` (see my updated snippet)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ant-d with sass as they are using less and they say to change it to sass will lead to breaking change and big overwrite [refer here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8619#issuecomment-351738273).
`We are using Less as the development language for styling. A set of less variables are defined for each design aspect that can be customized to your needs.` quote from there website [Link](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-themeare)

But there is a way to use sass with ant-design, with the help of this package
[antd-scss-theme-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-scss-theme-plugin),
you can read more in this post [Link](https://intoli.com/blog/antd-scss-theme-plugin/)